# What type of the following Conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

What type of conditional is the following sentence:

> If you think that that contact is not going to last awhile, you got another thought coming.

Answer (score 4):

It's an ordinary present-tense inferential<sup>†</sup>. You may be confused by that *got*: it's not a past-tense form of got but an abbreviated form of the present-tense idiom *have/has got* meaning *have*. It is very common in US speech to reduce  *have* or omit it entirely. Paraphrase:

> If you think that X, you have another thought coming.

The idiom *you have* (or *got*) *another thought* (or *think*) *coming* means "You should reconsider your expectation/opinion".

<sup>†</sup> <sup>You may have been taught to call this the "first conditional" or the "zero conditional". These are terms used only by teachers, not linguists.</sup>

Comment: You might expand your footnote to include _", nor native speakers, most of whom have no idea what it means and have never heard it."_ (Or is that too broad?)

Comment: @StoneyB,but in 1st conditional If+V1,will+V1 structure is used instead of if +V1,has/have V3...

Comment: @M.NaeemAhmad I've adjusted my footnote to include an alternative term some teachers use. But frankly I  don't pay a lot of attention to the n-conditionals, and I suggest you ignore them, too. They don't tell you anything useful. ... By the way, *thought* is not a past participle ('V3')--it's a noun.